# How to define AmqpSource to subscribe to multiple exchange?

Tags: scala, akka, alpakka

Right now i am subscribing to single exchange using

```
AmqpSource.atMostOnceSource(
    NamedQueueSourceSettings(..))
```

I want to be able to subscribe to multiple exchange. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's nothing specific for this for a particular alpakka source you can use either a Merge or MerbeHub.

If you know all of the sources up front you can combine multiple Sources into one using a [Merge](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-graphs.html)

If you don't know all of the sources up front you can use a [MergeHub](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html?language=scala#using-the-mergehub) e.g.

```
// A simple consumer that will print to the console for now  
val consumer = Sink.foreach(println)

// Attach a MergeHub Source to the consumer. This will materialize to a
// corresponding Sink.
val runnableGraph: RunnableGraph[Sink[String, NotUsed]] =
  MergeHub.source[String](perProducerBufferSize = 16).to(consumer)

// By running/materializing the consumer we get back a Sink, and hence
// now have access to feed elements into it. This Sink can be materialized
// any number of times, and every element that enters the Sink will
// be consumed by our consumer.
val toConsumer: Sink[String, NotUsed] = runnableGraph.run()

// Feeding two independent sources into the hub.
AmqpSource.atMostOnceSource(
   NamedQueueSourceSettings(..)).runWith(toConsumer)
AmqpSource.atMostOnceSource(
   NamedQueueSourceSettings(..)).runWith(toConsumer)
```

Comment: is this for producer code, I want to be able to consume from multiple exchange

Comment: This is for consumer, the messages will go to the Sink.foreach and be printed